# Eclipse does not start anymore?

Tags: java, eclipse, cocoa

I have used Eclipse in Mac OSX Lion for months. Today when I start Eclipse, it does not start anymore. I tried to open it from the terminal and get this error:
*****WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.**

I tried adding -clean -XstartOnFirstThread but the problem persist. This is weird because it worked fine last night.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that there is an Eclipse process already (still) running (Eclipse didn't shut down correctly last night). Did you check in the Activity Monitor. If there is a process running, kill it. If not, I would restart your machine before checking anything else.

Comment: I have tried restart the system, but it does not solve the problem. However, if I log in with another account then it works fine. I recently install a plug-in for editing python from eclipse, could that be the problem?